# File uploads in node.js as nginx upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node app running through nginx as an upstream and doing file uploads up to 2GB.

In nginx, I have `client_max_body_size` set to `2G` and increased `client_body_buffer_size` to `2mb`.

I find that when uploading large files (eg, 1gb), it will hang in nginx for a really long time (30 seconds +) until it makes it to node (which actually handles the upload).

I have logs in nginx for `[warn] 9624#0: *586 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /usr/share/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000032`

Any ideas why it's not passing to node right away or how I can optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

it has been really long since this question has been asked but nginx has `proxy_request_buffer` which can be set to off (it is on by default).